# Showing Readable Diffs in Version Control for provided SQL-scripts in Data Flows in Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql, git, azure-devops, version-control, azure-data-factory

### Issue

To cleanly version-control & code-review development in ADF, it would be desirable to show readable/comprehensible diffs for [scripts in SQL provided in the Source-Option Query of the Data Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VphdI.png).

While ADF does support versioning by defining all objects in *diffable* .jsons, **the format of the provided SQL-query in the "script":"query" of the Data Flow .json is awkwardly formatted (single line, newline characters, jumbled up with other parameters etc.) and therefore unsuited for showing nice diffs for a proper code-review/version-control in case of new additions or changes**, see example below:

```
{
    "name": "computeDataFlowName",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DatabaseName",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "computeDataFlowName"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [],
            "transformations": [],
            "script": "source(output(\n\t\tlead_id as string,\n\t\tfrom_ts as timestamp,\n\t\tto_ts as timestamp,\n\t\tstatus as string,\n\t\tprev_status as string,\n\t\tis_current_status as integer,\n\t\tcreated_by_id as string\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tisolationLevel: 'READ_UNCOMMITTED',\n\tquery: '\\nSELECT\\n\t\tLeadId AS lead_id,\\n\t\t\\n\t\tCreatedDate AS from_ts,\t\t\\n\t\tLEAD(\\n\t\tCreatedDate,\\n\t\t1\\n\t)  \\n\t\t    OVER (\\n\t\t\t\tPARTITION BY LeadId\\n\tORDER BY\\n\t\t\t\tCreatedDate\\n\t) AS to_ts,\\n\t\t\\n\t\tNewValue AS status,\\n\t\tOldValue AS prev_status,\t\t\\n\t\tCASE\\n\t\tWHEN\\n\t\t\tLEAD(\\n\t\t\tCreatedDate,\\n\t\t\t1\\n\t\t)  \\n\t\t\t    OVER (\\n\t\t\t\t\tPARTITION BY LeadId\\n\t\tORDER BY\\n\t\t\t\t\tCreatedDate\\n\t\t)\\n\t\t\tIS NULL\\n\t\tTHEN 1\\n\t\tELSE 0\\n\tEND AS is_current_status,\t\t\\n\t\tCreatedById AS created_by_id\\nFROM\\nlsh',\n\tformat: 'query') ~> computeDataFlowName"
        }
    }
}
```

### Possible Solution?

My first idea would be to find a way to add a relative reference (parameter?) into the "script":"query", which points to a separately stored .sql file, which would then be properly reviewable and show nice diffs when created/modified.

i.e. **is there a way to provide a wildcard file path for SQL query in a Data Flow which is feed by a file-location/url, so that I can separately manage & review the .sql scripts, instead of having to track them through the awkward .json from ADF?**

Any pointers or workarounds?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, my first thought is:

1. Store your SQL script file in Azure DevOps (or whatever version control thing you got going)
2. Create a Variable on your pipeline (eg YourSQLtext).
3. Do an API Call via Data Factory to get the contents of the file from Azure DevOps
4. Write the API Response output to the "YourSQLText" variable
5. Use that variable in your data flow or copy activity

Here is the link to the Azure DevOps Get Item contents REST API Call:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Using these steps you could have your SQL stored in version control and called in the pipeline to be used in your Data Flow or Copy data activity.

Comment: I have called the REST API before, but unfortunately don't have an example handy. Let me know if you need help and I can assist. Authenticating in Azure DevOps is annoying. Short term you can use a Personal Access Token, long term you should set up an app registration.